# Java reading a .txt file with scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am currently writing a program that reads a given .txt through the runtime args[0]. When reading that file with the scanner class, I'm struggling to format what has been read with the use of Delimiters.;

The data in the .txt file looks like this:

```
A 1 2 3 4
B 5 6
7 8 9 10
C
11 12
13
14
```

The output I am currently receiving is:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6
7 8 9 10

11 12
13
14
```

The desired output is where the delimiters are used to split up the inputs but rather than keeping them in the same line by line format, conjoin the inputs until the delimiter is met.

Something like this:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14
```

My current code for this is:

```
public static void readFile(String args) throws Exception
    {
        FileReader file = new FileReader(args);
        Scanner fromStr;
        fromStr = new Scanner(file);
        fromStr.useDelimiter("A|B|C");
    
    
        while (fromStr.hasNext())
        {
            String temp = fromStr.next();
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
    
        fromStr.close();
    }
```

I'm fairly new to this concept, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am only seeing the `C` delimiter in the input file. You can't get the desired output with the defined delimiter

Comment: Your code input/output doesn't match with the code you provided. Please provide valid examples, otherwise the question is too broad

Comment: does that '>' also needs to be taken care? or is it just for demonstration ?

Comment: Edited: Matched correct code and formatted input and outputs.

Comment: It seems you just need to remove any line breaks (from 'temp' string)